# List of asymptotic expressions for $\sum_r r^\beta \ln r$?

Tags: sequences-and-series, asymptotics

### Expression for $\beta =1$ in $\sum_r r^\beta \ln r$

I recently had the following idea to use the below identity:

$$ (1!2! 3! \dots n!) (12^2 3^3 4^4 \dots n^n) = n!^{n+1}$$

Dividing both sides by $n^{n(n+1)/2}$ and using $1+2+3 \dots + n = \frac{n(n+1)}{2}$:

$$ (1!2! 3! \dots n!) (\frac{1}{n}(\frac{2}{n})^2 (\frac{3}{n})^3 (\frac{4}{n})^4 \dots (\frac{n}{n})^n) = \frac{n!^{n+1}}{n^{n(n+1)/2}}$$

Raising both sides to power $1/n$:

$$ (1!2! 3! \dots n!)^{\frac{1}{n}} ((\frac{1}{n})^{\frac{1}{n}}(\frac{2}{n})^{\frac{2}{n}} (\frac{3}{n})^{\frac{3}{n}} (\frac{4}{n})^{\frac{4}{n}} \dots (\frac{n}{n})^{\frac{1}{n}}) = \frac{n!^{1+1/n}}{n^{(n+1)/2}}$$

Taking $\ln$ both sides:

$$ \sum_{r=1}^n \ln(r!) \frac{1}{n} + \sum_{r=1}^n \frac{r}{n} \ln(\frac{r}{n}) = \ln(\frac{n!^{1+1/n}}{n^{(n+1)/2}}) $$

Dividing both sides with $1/n$:

$$ \sum_{r=1}^n \ln(r!) \frac{1}{n^2} + \sum_{r=1}^n \frac{r}{n} \ln(\frac{r}{n})\frac{1}{n} = \frac{1}{n} \ln(\frac{n!^{1+1/n}}{n^{(n+1)/2}}) $$

In the limit $n \to \infty $ then $ \sum_{r=1}^n \frac{r}{n} \ln(\frac{r}{n})\frac{1}{n} \to \int_0^1 x \ln x dx = -1/4 $. Hence,

$$ \sum_{r=1}^n \ln(r!) \frac{1}{n^2}  - \frac{1}{4}\sim \frac{1}{n} \ln(\frac{n!^{1+1/n}}{n^{(n+1)/2}}) $$

Thus,

$$ \sum_{r=1}^n \ln(r!)\frac{1}{n^2} \sim  (1+ \frac{1}{n} ))( n \ln(n) -n + O(\ln n)) - \frac{(n+1)}{2}\ln(n) + \frac{1}{4} $$

Using Stirling's approximation on the R.H.S:

$$ \sum_{r=1}^n \ln(r!)\frac{1}{n^2} \sim  \frac{n-1}{2} \ln n + \ln n  -\frac{3}{4} + O(\frac{\ln n}{n}) $$

Using Stirling's approximation on the L.H.S:

$$ \sum_{r=1}^n(r \ln r  + r + O(\ln r))\frac{1}{n^2}  \sim  \frac{n-1}{2} \ln n + \ln n  -\frac{3}{4} + O(\frac{\ln n}{n}) $$

Simplifying both sides:

$$ \sum_{r=1}^n r \ln r  \sim  n^2 \frac{n-1}{2} \ln n + n^2\ln n  -\frac{(5n+2)n}{4} + O(n \ln n + \ln n!) $$

### Question

I did not consider the error when converting to an integral when I did the step "In the limit $n \to \infty $ then $ \sum_{r=1}^n \frac{r}{n} \ln(\frac{r}{n})\frac{1}{n} \to \int_0^1 x \ln x dx = -1/4 $" .. What is the error? Is there a list of asymptotic expressions for $\sum r^\beta \ln r$ without using $ \sum r^\beta \leq \sum r^\beta \ln r \leq \sum r^{\beta + 1}$?

Comment: The sum must be asymptotic to the antiderivative, i.e. $\sim x^{\beta+1}\log x/(\beta+1)$.

Comment: The original identity is not true for $n=2$? I think you meant $(n!)^{n+1}$.

Comment: @PeterForeman Your right it the R.H.S should be $n!^{n+1}$ ... Sigh ... I'll edit the post

Comment: Edited the post :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By the Euler-Maclaurin summation formula,

$$\sum_{k=1}^nk^\beta\ln k\approx\frac{n^{\beta+1}}{\beta+1}\log n-\frac{n^{\beta+1}-1}{(\beta+1)^2}+\frac{n^\beta\ln n}2+\frac{\beta n^{\beta-1}\ln n-n^{\beta-1}+1}{12}+\cdots$$